# How to update a table after an insert in another table with mysql?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger to update a table (customer) after an insert in another table (invoice), here is where I'm stuck :

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_invoice AFTER INSERT ON invoice FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
SET @TIME=new.paid_time
SET @id=new.id_customer
UPDATE customer SET bank_time = bank_time + @TIME WHERE id = @id
END |
delimiter ;
```

I expect a total of 01:30:00 when bank_time = 00:00:00 and paid_time = 01:30:00. But this is setting bank_time to NULL and I can't figure out why.

Here are the tables structures:

```
CREATE TABLE `customer` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `bank_time` TIME NULL DEFAULT '00:00:00',
    `country` VARCHAR(25) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `NAME` VARCHAR(25) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

CREATE TABLE `invoice` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `paid_time` TIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `id_customer` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `id_customer` (`id_customer`),
    CONSTRAINT `invoice_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_customer`) REFERENCES `customer` (`id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

For some reasons I'm unable to comment but here is what I tried after @GMB answer but still without luck:

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_invoice AFTER INSERT ON invoice FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

    SET @TIME = new.paid_time,
    SET @identif = new.id_customer,
    UPDATE customer SET bank_time = ADDTIME(COALESCE(bank_time, 0), @TIME) WHERE id = @identif;

END |
delimiter ;
```

Comment: I don't know if session variables are case sensitive in MySQL, but `@TIME` may not be the same thing as `@time`.

Comment: "User variable names are **not** case-sensitive." https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html

Comment: Side note : aren't you missing a  `WHERE` clause in your update query ?

Comment: You're right, did not realise, I copied the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to notice is that, if `bank_time` is `NULL`, adding anything to it will still yield `NULL`. `COALESCE` can be used to handle that use case.

Also, it is a good practice to use [MySQL ADDTIME() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime) to add times, instead of using the regular addition operation.

I would suggest to replace this :

```
UPDATE customer SET bank_time = bank_time + @time WHERE id = @id
```

With :

```
UPDATE customer SET bank_time = ADDTIME(COALESCE(bank_time, 0), @time) WHERE id = @id
```

**[See this db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sTbP6EENH6oxZULuEfGrLf/3)** for a demo ; you can comment/uncomment your previous version and compare its results to the new one.

Comment: after reviewing the code I was missing the ';' and that was creating the problem, your suggestion works for me, thanks you